# iOS image resize: is there a better interpolation than the kCGInterpolationHigh?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, interpolation, image-resizing

I use this method to resize an image to the double of its original dimensions:

```
- (UIImage *)doubleSizeImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width*2, image.size.height*2);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
 }
```

The fact is that the interpolation is still poor: I can see well the pixelated effect which, for example, iOS Safari doesn't have when zooming pages. So I was wondering if there a better way to upscale an image, also using a third party library/category or something like that? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually using kCGInterpolationHigh? What if you get rid of that line... does it look the same? Just double checking. Also, it would be helpful if you shared the results of this vs. Safari just for our information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you interpolate, you're going to get some kind of artifacts.

Safari doesn't get artifacts on the page because the page is essentially a vector document, with outline fonts and resizable objects—but if you look at a raster image on the page, you'll see that if you blow it up big enough, the image will indeed show artifacts. Safari is not immune; nothing is.

Comment: I know that, and I was not talking about the vector parts. Given the same zoom, images on safari simply are better interpolated: of course with artifacts, but better "blurred". In my app, the same image at the same size is just more pixelated. But hey, I guess that in the end it's just ok.

Comment: @AndreaSprega: It's possible that Safari is using a different interpolation level that you prefer, or that it is changing the size of a layer (and I don't know how that relates to any of the interpolation values or the current one in the view's context).